# Adding popup to Leaflet but only on click?

Tags: leaflet, popup, markers

As there a way to add a popup to a marker but only show it when it is clicked?

As it seems to be default to show it when one is loaded.  This is no good when markers are getting updated.

Currently using this

```
 mymarker = new L.Marker(e.latlng, {
                icon: yellowIcon,
               draggable: true
             });


             map.addLayer(mymarker);
             mymarker.bindPopup('<p>You are here ' + username + '</p>').openPopup();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just leave out call of `.openPopup()` method:

```
mymarker.bindPopup('<p>You are here ' + username + '</p>');
```